# Python - Adding top level comments by lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am using the python2.6 and lxml, I want to add the top level comments into the xml like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!--top level comment-->
<DCSubtitle/>
```

I google this addprevious() method to do that, Here is my code:

```
root = ET.Element("DCSubtitle")
root.addprevious(ET.Comment('top level comment'))
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(sys.stdout, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

But, the addprevious() seems to be not very logical, you have to add the second line and then you add the first line, is there any better logical way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is no another way.
Even lxml maintainer Stefan Behnel has proposed addprevious method.