# How to append comment to XML file after XML declaration using Python?

Tags: python, xml, comments, elementtree, tostring

I create a root:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring

root = Element("root")
```

Then generating a string repr of XML:

```
xmlstr = tostring(root, encoding="utf8", method="xml")
```

And create my xml file:

```
        myFile = open(file, "w")
        myFile.write(xmlstr)
        myFile.close()
```

After all operations my file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
</root>
```

What I should do to add some comments after xml declaration? Tried to use xml.etree.ElementTree.Comment but not sure how to do it properly. My desirable file should looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- My comments -->
<root>
</root>
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand something. Thanks!

Comment: With lxml instead of ElementTree, you can use `getprevious()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69652602/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23025245/407651

Comment: Will check it :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `addprevious()`!

Comment: It is possible to use xml.etree? Or only via lxml?

Comment: If you cannot use lxml, maybe you can read the file as plain text (not parsed XML) to add your comment after the first line, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653155/407651

Comment: But for:
r+ - open for reading and writing. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.
a+ - open for reading and appending (writing at end of file).

In case of r+, my first line in xml declaration so I can't do that. Using seek is also bad because it will overwrite xml declaration if I choose seek(0,1) or something like that. On the other hand, append will add my comment at the end of file but in this case I can't use seek function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. Provide both the XML declaration and the comment as a "header" string.

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, tostring

header = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- My comments -->
"""

root = Element("root")
xmlstr = tostring(root).decode()

# Create a file with header + xmlstr
with open("out.xml", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as out:
    out.write(header + xmlstr)
```

Resulting content in out.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- My comments -->
<root />
```

Comment: Will check it and let you know ;)

Comment: Almost perfect, 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <!-- My comments -->
            <root>`

As you can see, there are additionaly tabs. How can I remove them? Maybe strip func?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't get any tabs, but there are line breaks. The output is almost exactly what you call "My desirable file".

Comment: Yes, I made mistake by my side, everything is ok! ;) Thank you a lot for help!